Position Layout with 2 weight(1f) elements
Here is my simplified layout:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {
    Text(
        text = "Title",
    )
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f, fill = false)
            .heightIn(max = IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Button(
        onClick = { },
    ) {
        Text(text = "Action",)
    }
}

The goal is for image take all the place, but not more, then a specific size. At the same time I wanna have Button at the bottom of the screen. In provided example Spacer and Image will take the equal amount of space, but I want weight(1f) to be fully applied to the Image and only after apply Spacer the the remaining part of the screen.
Meaning, for a small device the Image could be less, than IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT and there is no Spacer at all. But for big device Image took IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT and the remaining part goes to the Spacer.

Is the code you posted not working? What exactly is happening? You can edit your post and include a screenshot of how it looks like with your current code.

There are complicated options (like ConstraintLayout). But this worked for me:
  Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Column( // This extra column wrapper
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f),
        ) {
            Text(...)
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f, fill = false)
                    .heightIn(max = IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT),
                ...
            )
        }
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = Spacings.Two),
        ) {
            ...
        }
    }

